# Executing Multiple Instances of Code Snippet at Specific Intervals Using Constant Timestamp

Tags: go, time, concurrency, blockchain, goroutine

I need to run multiple instances of the same code snippet at regular intervals. For example, I want to run four instances, where the first instance starts executing 5 seconds after a constant timestamp (e.g., 3PM), the second instance starts 10 seconds after, the third instance starts 15 seconds after, and the fourth instance starts 20 seconds after. Additionally, I want to repeat this pattern periodically, with the first instance starting again at 25 seconds after the constant timestamp and so on. How can I achieve this scheduling arrangement in my code?

I was trying using time.Ticker object in go, but was unable to come up with a solution to this, basically what I am looking for is, that I am passing in the ID to each instance while executing them, and then I want them to call a function after a particular multiple of seconds have passed since a t=0.

```
// We'll make a ticker that ticks every 5*nodeID seconds
proposalTicker := time.NewTicker(time.Duration(5*nodeID) * time.Second)
// Execute the proposal function every time the ticker ticks
go func() {
    for range proposalTicker.C {
        // Propose a new block 
        node.ProposeBlock() 
    }
}()
```

Comment: What happens if the execution of these functions bleed into the tick of the next eligible one? Do you allow for overlapping execution?

Comment: You don't have to multiply the 5 seconds with anything. Just count the ticks and use count%4 to decide which function to call.